# How to remove background color of text fields in Material Design

Tags: android, material-design, textfield, android-theme, android-textinputlayout

In newer versions of material design library, the appearance of text fields has changed.

How can I revert it to its older style (without gray background and without complete border)?

From this:
[image]
To this:
[image]

Image credits: [this Medium article](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/migrating-to-material-components-for-android-ec6757795351)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This change is based on a [user research](https://medium.com/google-design/the-evolution-of-material-designs-text-fields-603688b3fe03) and was introduced in version **1.1.0** of material design library for android ([MDC](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android)). If you want the legacy look-and-feel, the official docs recommends this method:

**Change a single text field:**

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    ...
    style="@style/Widget.Design.TextInputLayout">
    ...
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

**Change all text fields in your theme:**

```
<style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.*">
    ...
    <item name="textInputStyle">@style/Widget.MyApp.TextInputLayout</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.MyApp.TextInputLayout" parent="Widget.Design.TextInputLayout">
    <!-- My custom attrs -->
</style>
```